# How to get the "Loss of Cabin Pressure" achievement?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I have tried this achievement twice now, arriving in sector 8 with 13% net oxygen, however the achievement doesn't trigger:

[image: Achievement not unlocked]

[image: ship layout]

Each time I only have two rooms pressurized, any time my doors are force closed due to hacking I simply cut the oxygen to the whole ship. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: grats for pulling it off twice for what its worth

Comment: I was wondering the same thing.  I had a run where I vented my ship the entire way with only Lanius crew on board but I didn't get it either since I had saved and quit at some point.

Comment: I did my whole run with 0% air - just let the non-Lanius crew die over and over and come back with the Clone Bay - of course, that was the first thing I upgraded to prevent permanent death!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On the FTL wiki page for the achievement it states:

> ATTENTION: Achievement is currently bugged - you may not save & quit during the achievement run.

I'd assume that that is what's causing your problem, since it sounds like everything else you're doing is a-ok.

Comment: That sounds about right. I guess I'll try a third time without saving.